# Facebook API (v3.2) - fan_count returns 0 using page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Request:
GET /v3.2/565231620165956?fields=fan_count,username

Response:
{
  "fan_count": 0,
  "username": "shirleysetia",
  "id": "565231620165956"
}

Page access token used.

Comment: Can’t reproduce, works for several pages I have admin access to, using either a page token or my admin user token. Looking at the page in Facebook, it seems to have quite a high number of likes though, maybe the API is buggy somehow. Do you have any other pages you have admin access to, that you could test this with?

Comment: Yes you are right. I can see the fan_count for the pages I have admin access to, using either a page token or my admin user token.

But it was not the case before. Previously it was possible to view the fan_count for all the pages.

Comment: Oh I assumed  you meant a page token for that page, not just any … This is not possible any more, you would have to submit your app for review for the Public Page Content Access feature to be able to get this kind of info from pages you have no admin access to, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS